# Move data between DBaaS with Azure pipeline

Tags: oracle, azure

I need to move data from tst DBaaS to acc DBaaS, DBaaS are not connected as azure resource or something like that.

Im trying to select some data from DBaaS A and insert it in DBaaS B using Linux Agent.
I have connections and passwords, user names are valid, i can see selected data in logs.

But how to make SELECT X FROM A and then INSERT X INTO B?

pool:
name: LinuxAgent

variables:

- name: a_name
  value: a_value
- name: a_connection
  value: a_connection
- name: b_name
  value: b_value
- name: b_connection
  value: b_connection

stages:

- stage: pull
  displayName: Pull data from DBaaS
  jobs:

  - job: pull
    steps:

    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Pull data
      inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
      sqlplus ${{ variables.a_name }}/PASSWORD@'${{ variables.a_connection }}' <<< "select query"
- stage: push
  displayName: Push data to DBaaS
  dependsOn:

  - pull
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
  - job: push
    steps:

    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Push data
      inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
      sqlplus ${{ variables.b_name }}/PASSWORD@'${{ variables.b_connection }}' <<< "insert query"`

My pipeline knowledge is pretty poor so beside of log query statement i have no idea how to store it and pass further...please help :)

Comment: Looks like you are using Azure DevOps as a data integration tool. This is not reccomended.  But if you really want to proceed with this approach, you first need to export the data to a flat file http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/oracle/Quickest-Way-to-Export-Data-to-File.html. This flat file will exist in a DevOps working directory. Then you need to import it with SQLLoader https://blogs.perficient.com/2017/03/03/processing-flat-files-in-oracle-database/ These two steps need to different jobs in the same stage otherwise you lose the intermediate flat file